# how to get a snapshot of current Java execution?

Tags: java

I know there is some program that comes with the JDK where you can get a snapshot of the execution of a Java program. I just can't recall the name (I thought it was jtrace), and I can't find it.

Looking on Google for "Tracing java programs" yields different solutions, none of which is the simple solution I am looking for.

(It would be also nice to get a memory snapshot, with objects and the amount of memory allocated for them, but I am not sure if that's possible with the program I have in mind.)

Does anyone know which program I am referring to?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "snapshot of current execution" if you're not referring to the memory state. Do you just want a debugger, to freeze and then step through the code? Most IDEs have this built in.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you are looking for, but could you use a debugger to get what you need?

Comment: I think they are called Profilers, you need to find out the memory usage of the application rite? even eclipse has it. check it out.

Comment: You may be looking for JVisualVM.

Comment: `jconsole` and `jvisualvm` both come with the JDK. One of those might be what you have in mind.

Comment: are you looking for jmap?

Comment: To get a snapshot you most likely just need (on windows) `Ctrl-Break` and on Unix  `Ctrl-\ ` or `kill -3 <java-pid>`

Comment: jstack. that's the one I was looking for. jmap also looks very interesting, but it doesn't work for me, it gives a Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process

Comment: Do you want a thread dump?  This shows all the threads running on the jvm process.  See @rolfl's note above.